# Can these types of Regexs be optimized?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on an app where we need to pull out key information from text. The catch is the text comes from OCRed documents, so there can be OCR recognition errors, noise, garbage characters, etc. Also, the text on the document can be in a million different formats depending on the source.

So, we use lots of regular expressions to pull out the text. We noticed that in high volume, this hammers the CPUs on the servers. I've tried pre-compiling the regexes and caching them without any improvement. Profiler shows 65% of the runtime is due to calling Regex.Match().

Reading up on regex, I see catastrophic backtracking is a performance issue.

Let's say I have an expression like this (this is a simple one just to illustrate the general format of our regexes -- others can contain many more keywords and formats):

```
(.*) KEYWORD1 AND (.* KEYWORD2)
```

When I step through with Regex Coach, I see it does a lot of backtracking to match the string.

Can this type of regex be conceptually improved? We do only run against a subset of the entire document (a smaller blob of text), but the preprocessing to pull out the blob isn't perfect either by nature.

So, yeah, pretty much anything can appear before "KEYWORD1" and anything can appear in front of "KEYWORD2", etc.

We can't restrict to A-Z instead of .*, since in the OCR world, letters can sometimes be mistake for numbers (i.e. Illene = I11ene), or we can get garbage characters in there due to OCR recognition errors.

Comment: regexes do go left to right so a trick I have used is to reverse the string, and 'flip' the regex.  So literally (2DROWYEK .*)  etc.  Just a thought.

Comment: @sniperd, some of our regexes end with .* too :).

Comment: What kinds of regexes do you have? If they’re all actually regular, you can use a DFA-based engine and match without backtracking. If they’re even more restricted (or restricted in other ways), there might be even simpler approaches.

Comment: Needs some kind of example. As it stands you are matching everything if it contains `KEYWORD1 AND` and up to `KEYWORD2`.

Comment: Do you have an _actual_ example? Or rather, an example of an expression that has bad performance?

Comment: The fewer `.*` closer to the left of the pattern the better. The first one is redundant. Optimization is possible but it can only be applied to an actual regex.

Comment: @MattBurland yeah, that's a actual example, I replaced the actual keywords in that example as not to get in trouble lol... but there are more complicated ones... but the general idea is to pull certain information out of legal documents.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is an actual regex (just one of the simpler ones)... we've got about 400 so far of similiar formats with .*'s in various locations in the strings to pull out the info.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, its basically what I explained in my post... its coming from OCR, so you can have junk everywhere in the string... typos, recognition errors, etc.

Comment: @Ryan, right now I'm using the standard .Net Regex. Is that DFA? Is there a DFA engine for C#? The majority of our expressions are of similair format... xxx and yyy, for zzz and we capture xxx, yyy, zzz, etc with .*'s in between the keywords.

Comment: Unroll the loop is what you may use, but manually unrolling 400 regexps is rather a time consuming task.

Comment: @SledgeHammer: I’m not asking about your engine (.NET regex is not DFA-based), but about your expressions. Are they restricted in any way, e.g. with the guarantee that the only patterns to match are either `.*` or literal text?

Comment: @Ryan.. oh... no, some use OR sets, optional characters, non capturing groups, repeat counts, word breaks, etc. I think they are all pretty basic like that.

Comment: You could write a .NET wrapper for https://github.com/google/re2. (There’s an existing one at https://github.com/0xcb/Re2.Net, but it looks unmaintained.)

Comment: @Ryan, cool, I'll try drop in that wrapper as is and see if there is a performance difference before I try to wrap the latest code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these types can be easily optimized.

You optimize them by replacing the regex with the intended code. That is to say, two substring searches. If the position of `" KEYWORD1 AND "` is smaller than that of `"KEYWORD2"` then you've got a match.

For extra speed, you can use optimized substring searches, but that's almost certainly not needed. Just eliminating the regex will give a massive speed boost.

[edit]
Ok, so there are 400. And some of them are slightly more complicated. The pattern remains the same: substantial substrings with little variation, that can be effectively located. If you know that `"PART OF"` occurs in your input, checking whether `" PART OF"` occurs can be done in approximately one nanosecond. And if `PARTF OF_  _doesn't_ occur, you don't need to check at all whether`AS PART OF` occurs.

Now 400 regexes is not much. If you had 40.000, it would be worthwhile to automate checking for common substrings. At the moment, you might just run each regex in turn, trying to match the other 399 regex *strings* to get a first cut. `.*PART OF.*` will match `".*AS PART OF.*"`.

For the same reason, you don't need other optimizations as well. With 40.000 regexes to match, I'd calculate the frequency of each letter pair. I.e. the input `FOO AS PART OF BAR` has letter pairs `FO, OO, PA, AR (twice), RT, OF, BA`. This cannot match `.*FOR EXAMPLE.*` as the letter pair `EX` is missing. right

Comment: I can't do that. We have about 400 regexes that we use to pull out certain parts of the text. Some of the more complicated ones have optional parts... like a keyword (phrase) might be "AS PART OF", but it could also be "PART OF", "PART    OF", ", PART OF", etc. All depends how it gets OCRed.